# Cannot add two values in assembly

Tags: assembly, addition

I am trying to learn some basic assembly language by reading documentation and tutorials online.

I have now written my first ever assembly program that shall add two values (s = x + y) and then set the sum as the exit value.

```
 .section .data
  x:   .int 40
  y:   .int 10
  sum: .int 0

.section .text

.globl _start
_start:
  movl x, %eax    ; move 40 to eax
  addl y, %eax    ; add 10 to eax
  movl %eax, sum  ; move eax to sum


  movl $1, sum    ; set sum as exit code
  int  $0x80
```

I am sure I have missunderstood something about the registers because I get a segmentation fault when executing my program. Is it possible to add several values to a register, like eax, without overwriting other values? Why do I get a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addition is fine, but you don't exit correctly.

```
; ...
movl %1, %eax ; sys_exit
movl sum, %ebx ; exit code in ebx
int $0x80
```

That's untested, but I think it'll fix you up.

Comment: That worked! Can you explain why the exit code must be in ebx and not in any other register?

Comment: Ask Linus. The system call number goes in `%eax`, first parameter goes in `%ebx`, second parameter goes in `%ecx`, third in `%edx, etc. Ask him why he changed it for 64-bit!!! :)